# MariaDB - breaking up a multi join into CTEs

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

So I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    i.mongodb_id
FROM
    display_list_lists dll
JOIN
    display_lists dl
    ON
        dll.display_list_id = dl._id
JOIN
    list_items li
    ON
    dll.list_id = li.list_id
JOIN
    items i
    ON
    li.item_id = i._id
WHERE
    dl.mongodb_id = ?
    AND
    dl.account_id = ?
```

since, I only need the `display_lists._id` in order to then find the other details, would it be better to somehow use CTEs instead?

Broken up, it would look like this:

```
SELECT
    _id
FROM
    display_lists dl
WHERE
    dl.mongodb_id = ?
    AND
    dl.account_id = ?;



SELECT
    *
FROM
    display_list_lists dll
WHERE
    dll.display_list_id = ?; // previous _id



SELECT
    *
FROM
    list_items li
WHERE
    li.list_id IN (?); // use list ids from previous results



SELECT
    *
FROM
    items i
WHERE
    i._id IN (?); // use item ids from previous results
```

Comment: *would it be better to somehow use CTEs instead?* No. 99.(9)% it will decrease performance.

Comment: @Akina that's interesting. So I guess my current query is good enough?

Comment: *I guess my current query is good enough?* Agreed. I have other preferences - I would write this query in Cartesian form. But it is only form, not content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would not be better to use a CTE in this instance. The advantage of (non-recursive) CTEs is only to do with readability and convenience, but in your case that doesn't apply. Your original query looks just fine.

Joining tables is what relational databases such as MariaDB do best. Joining 4 tables is a breeze, provided proper indexing is utilised.

Answer (score 2):

Your 'join' version is plenty good.  For performance, you need these indexes (or PKs):

```
dl:  (mongodb_id, account_id,  -- in either order
      id)                      -- third
dll:  (display_list_id, list_id)  -- in this order
li:  (list_id)
i:  (id, mongodb_id)   -- unless (id) is the PRIMARY KEY
```

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)